# How to remove date from a calendar built using toastui in R

Tags: r, calendar, htmlwidgets, toast-ui-editor

I have the created a weekly calendar in R below using [toastui](https://github.com/dreamRs/toastui):

```
library(toastui)
calendar(view="week", defaultDate = NULL) %>% cal_week_options(workweek = TRUE, hourStart = 7.5, hourEnd = 24)
```

This line of the code gives the following output:
[image]

How can I remove the dates i.e. 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 and just have Monday-Friday as the labels? I have been going through the documentation but I couldn't find a solution. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this question. It is quite simple. According to the [documentation](https://dreamrs.github.io/toastui/reference/cal_template.html) one needs to use [JS](https://rdrr.io/cran/htmlwidgets/man/JS.html) in order to update the names. The code below perfectly displays how the column values are updated:

```
library(toastui)
calendar(view="week", defaultDate = NULL) %>% 
  cal_week_options(workweek = TRUE, hourStart = 7.5, hourEnd = 24) %>% 
  cal_template(
    weekDayname = JS(
      "function(model) {",
      "var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];",
      "return '<span class=\"tui-full-calendar-dayname-name\">' + days[model.day] + '</span>';",
      "}"
    )
  )
```